# Is this really the best way to get a Rx.Observable from an event callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, rxjs, eventemitter

I want to get a stream of events from datamaps library but since that library is not really written with Reactive Programming in mind I'm having a difficult time to map any emitted event from it into an Observable. My best attempt so far is this, but it doesn't feel so idiomatic. Is this the best I can do or am I maybe missing some basic RxJs construct that would make this better/simpler/more readable?

```js
import Rx from 'rx';
import {EventEmitter} from 'events';
import Datamap from 'datamaps';

const eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
const mapEvents$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(
  eventEmitter,
  'mapEvent'
)
const map = new Datamap({
  element: document.getElementById('map'),
  done: (datamap) => {
    datamap.svg
      .selectAll('.datamaps-subunit')
      .on('mouseover', (o) => {
        eventEmitter.emit('mapEvent', o);
      });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using an EventEmitter as an event bus, but we already have [Subjects](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/subject.md) you could use instead. Subjects are both observers and observables, which means you can call `onNext` on them to give them the next event and you can use operators on the observable sequence.

Simply, I'd rewrite it to something like this:

```
import Rx from 'rx';
import Datamap from 'datamaps';

const datamapsSubject = new Rx.Subject();
const map = new Datamap({
  element: document.getElementById('map'),
  done: (datamap) => {
    datamap.svg
      .selectAll('.datamaps-subunit')
      .on('mouseover', (o) => {
        datamapsSubject.onNext(o);
      });
  }
});
```

If you need something you can construct on subscription and destroy on disposal/unsubscription, you might also consider [Observable.create](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/create.md), but it looks like you're only targeting that one div element for now.

Comment: Thanks so much @kakigoori! Getting rid of the `EventEmitter` feels so good :)

Comment: I actually tried something similar but couldn't get it to work because I missed out that `Rx.Subject()` actually needed to be initialized with the `new` keyword so abandoned it.